# Mongo subset query with indexing.

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I am attempting to optimize the for the following use case. I want to retrieve all documents whose array field is a subset of the querying array.

Ex. subset(['a', 'b', 'c']) => [{arr: ['a', 'b']}, {arr: ['c']}, {arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']}]

So far the query $not:{$elemMatch:{$nin:[arr]}} has allowed me to achieve the expected behavior. This query, however, does not use the index on array field I have selected, resulting in a full collection scan each time. I did some research, and apparently a $elemMatch preceded by a $not results in the index not being used. Is there any other way to reproduce my query such that it uses the index? This query currently takes almost a full second at 1M documents.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the $not used with $nin? Wouldn't $or [$in with {$exists: false}] suffice?

Could you provide your index and the executionStats of your query?
ex. db..find({}).explain('executionStats')